# How to change redirect path for drupal6 comment form

Tags: drupal

I have tried to change the comment form redirect path with the following code.

```
function Mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
 if($form_id=='comment_form' && arg(0)=='writing'){
   $form['#redirect'] = 'writing/'.arg(1); 
 }
}
```

But it does not works.Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the arg(0) is 'writing'...? Make sure `if condition` is true. I have tried below code and working fine.

```
function mymod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id=='comment_form' ){
    $form['#redirect'] = 'node'; 
  }
}
```